# Why not able to get h3,h4 as previous element through BeautifuSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the previous element of the h4 tag. I tried previous_element, previous_sibling, but not able to traverse h3.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup('''
    <html>
<body>
        <h3 class="typography-body block-link profile-name">My H3 Tag</h3>
<h4 class="typography-body typography-profile-title">
                                   THis is H4 tag
                                </h4>
</body>
    </html>
    ''', "lxml")

hh = soup.find('h4')
print(hh.previous_sibling)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find previous subling you don't need to find it just call : `soup.tag.previous_sibling.previous_sibling`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('''
    <html>
<body>
        <h3 class="typography-body block-link profile-name">My H3 Tag</h3>
<h4 class="typography-body typography-profile-title">
                                   THis is H4 tag
                                </h4>
</body>
    </html>
    ''', "html.parser")

print(soup.h4.previous_sibling.previous_sibling)
```

**Output**

```
<h3 class="typography-body block-link profile-name">My H3 Tag</h3>
```

To get only the text inside the tags you can use :

```
print(soup.h4.previous_sibling.previous_sibling.text)
```

**Output**

```
My H3 Tag
```

Comment: Thanks!! This worked for me... I never knew to use previous_sibling twice to fetch the previous sibling...!

Answer (score 1):

Try `findPreviousSibling()`

```
hh = soup.find('h4')
print(hh.findPreviousSibling())
```

And would recommend to please go through the [BeautifulSoup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as it is well documentated

Comment: Thanks for sparing time to give the solution and especially the link of Documentation! It's awesome...Somehow findPreviousSibling() did not work for me... I had to call previous_sibling twice as suggested by @Adgogo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` to select for an h3 that has an immediately adjacent h4 by adding in an adjacent sibling combinator (+)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
    <html>
    <body>
        <h3 class="typography-body block-link profile-name">My H3 Tag</h3>
        <h4 class="typography-body typography-profile-title">
            THis is H4 tag
        </h4>
    </body>
</html>''', "lxml")
print(soup.select_one('h3:has(+h4)').text)
```